# Create a Dataframe import several sheets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have three excel files and each one has 12 sheets. I would like to create a dataframe joining all the sheets of the three files with a column with the sheet number. So far I have the following code:

```
path <- 'PRT 2017.xlsx' #Just one file
sheets <- excel_sheets(path)
df2017 <- map_df(sheets,~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x), .id = "sheet")
```

but it generates the following error:

Error: Column `ZZn` can't be converted from character to numeric
Además: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

The structure of a sheet (sheetname: 201701) is:

```
FF                          ZN   ZZn     Q  
28/01/2017 09:07:32 a.m.   612   61201   4
12/01/2017 06:49:01 a.m.   728   DFT     10
```

and the result that I would like is:

```
FF                          ZN   ZZn     Q   Sheet
28/01/2017 09:07:32 a.m.   612   61201   4   201701
12/01/2017 06:49:01 a.m.   728   DFT     10  201701
28/02/2018 04:21:34 p.m.   405   40502   20  201802
```

Thanks...

Comment: Does this work? `df2017 <- map_df(sheets, read_excel(path, sheet = .x), .id = "sheet")`. You are not really using a formula here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that for some sheets `ZZn` contains only numeric values while for others it also contains characters. As a consequence for some sheets `ZZn` is a numeric vector while for others it is a character vector. However binding the df's together does not work in that case. This is what the error message is telling you.

As an example have a look at this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sheets <- list(
  a = data.frame(
    ZN = c(1, 2),
    ZZn = c(61201, "DFT"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ),
  b = data.frame(
    ZN = c(3, 4),
    ZZn = c(61201, 61202),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
)

# Error
map_df(sheets, ~ .x, .id = "sheet")
#> Error: Column `ZZn` can't be converted from character to numeric

# Works
map_df(sheets, ~ mutate(.x, ZZn = as.character(ZZn)), .id = "sheet")
#>   sheet ZN   ZZn
#> 1     a  1 61201
#> 2     a  2   DFT
#> 3     b  3 61201
#> 4     b  4 61202
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Therefore you have to convert the numeric vectors to characters before binding the sheets together, like so

```r
map_df(sheets, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x) %>% 
  mutate(ZZn = as.character(ZZn)), .id = "sheet")
```